# Substring in python resulting column object being not callable

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm working on Pyspark, created a sample dataframe with some long and decimal type columns.
Here I wanted to fetch decimal type column value to two decimal points without rounding. Below is the code I tried.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  (324.456, "hi", "test"),
  (453.987, "hello", "python"),
  (768.66, "test", "java")
  ], ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
)
new = df.withColumn(
 "col4",
 F.substring((df.col1).cast(StringType()),1,F.instr((df.col1).cast(StringType()),".")+2))
```

So here I'm converting the column into string and finding he index position adding two (because I need two decimal points without rounding). But I don't **what's the mistake here I'm getting `Column` object is not callable error**. If I'm using only F.instr() function it is working fine. Kindly help with my other solution two fetch the value to two decimals without rounding.

```sh
Expected output
col1     col2   col3   col4
324.456  hi     test   324.45
453.987  hello  python 453.98
768.66   test   java   768.66
```

Comment: why you don't want to  use rounding?

Comment: @moeassal, I have requirement to fetch to two decimals without rounding to use in my join condition.

Comment: @hunter did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a regular expression with `regexp_extract` here:

```
df.withColumn('test',
              F.regexp_extract(F.col("col1").cast("string"),'\d+[.]\d{2}',0)).show()
```

Or as @MohammadMurtazaHashmi sugested in comments no casting required:

```
df.withColumn('test',F.regexp_extract(F.col("col1"),'\d+[.]\d{2}',0)).show()
```

---

```
+-------+-----+------+------+
|   col1| col2|  col3|  test|
+-------+-----+------+------+
|324.456|   hi|  test|324.45|
|453.987|hello|python|453.98|
| 768.66| test|  java|768.66|
+-------+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: u dont need to cast to string, regexp takes it like one. nice solution tho

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a way of truncating decimals. I propose you use `pyspark.sql.functions.pow` and some clever use of casting to `LongType` for this. This way, you multiply by `10^{decimal_places}` and divide by the same again, while casting to `long` to get rid of decimals (floats) in between, such as:

```
df2.show()
+-------+-----+------+
|   col1| col2|  col3|
+-------+-----+------+
|324.456|   hi|  test|
|453.987|hello|python|
| 768.66| test|  java|
+-------+-----+------+


decimal_places = 2
truncated_value_column = f.pow(f.lit(10), decimal_places).cast('long')

df2.withColumn(
    "trunc", 
    ((f.col("col1") * truncated_value_column)).cast("long") / truncated_value_column
).show()
+-------+-----+------+------+
|   col1| col2|  col3| trunc|
+-------+-----+------+------+
|324.456|   hi|  test|324.45|
|453.987|hello|python|453.98|
| 768.66| test|  java|768.66|
+-------+-----+------+------+
```

NB: If you then wish to cast back to `string`, I recommend you do so afterwards. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer, I will try and let you know